# Using a for loop iterator to shorten a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to shorten a 2.5k line function into something far more manageable using a few for loops. I've managed to stifle off all syntax errors after a lot of changes. However what was an originally extremely long but working function, has now turned into a much shorter but broken function. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong.

This is the essence of what I'm trying to do:

```
function countryChange() {
    //Blank auto complete box
    for(var i=0; i<30; i++){
        for(var q=5; q<7; q++){
            for(var u=0; u<3; u++){
                $("#_Q6_Q".concat(toString(i),"_Q", toString(q), "_Q0_Q", toString(u))).val('');
            };
        };
        $("#_Q6_Q".concat(toString(i),"_Q4_Q0_Q0")).val('');
    };
```

The function goes on a bit more, but everything is essentially a repetition, using for loops to generate a series of numbers which is then put into a few statements.

Without the for loops there are 30*3*3 variations of the _Q6_Q#_Q#_Q0_Q# which all have to be used and reused several times.

Also it might be worth noting that this is to use the JQuery AutoComplete widget:
http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

I wrote the previous 2.5k line script with Python which I'm more comfortable with and could generate all the large repetitive could with.

Fixed for now: had to change toString() to String(). Although some have mentioned that that isn't needed at all.

Comment: toString is a function defined elsewhere?

Comment: Can't you just write `$('[id^="_Q6_Q"]').val('')` to empty all elements whose id starts with `_Q6_Q`?

Comment: Did you forget the closing bracket `}` or is it intentional?

Comment: In addition to `johnnycardy` comment: If you did not define `toString` yourself, then you call `toString`of `window` which would result in `[object Object]`. You could try `String(i)` to see if your result is then correct or just `.concat(i, ...)`.

Comment: Why the `.concat()` and `toString()` at all? `$("#_Q6_Q" + i + "_Q" + q + "_Q0_Q" + u)`

Comment: The unclosed bracket is intentional, theres a lot more code before the function ends.

Comment: Concat was just to be safe (fairly new to js) but I will remove it. toString I thought was standard JS. Is it not? I'll try with string()

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you split the problems, and create the numbers you'll later crunch within an array, and then define what will be the crunching function, then crunch the array :

```
function createArray () {
       var res=[];
       var i,q,u;
        for(i=0; i<30; i++){
            for(q=5; q<7; q++){
                for(u=0; u<3; u++) {
                     res.push([i:i, q:q, u:u]);
                    };
                };
            };
 }

// just build it once and store it
var myIndexes = createArray();
```

After that the processing can be done with one forEach for all your loops.

```
myIndexes.forEach(resetAutoCompleteComboBox);
```

with :

```
function resetAutoCompleteComboBox(a) {
      var i=toString(a.i);
      var q=toString(a.q);
      var u=toString(a.u);
      $("#_Q6_Q" + i + "_Q" + q + "_Q0_Q" + u)).val('');          
}
```

If you take advantage of the similarity of the processing functions, you might also be able to do some other useful code factorisation.

Comment: That's a really neat way to condense everything. Thanks. I'll put it to use! Turned out the issue with the code however was my use of toString() when it should have just been string(), or without any function as some have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Might be better to use jQuery's built in sizzle selectors:

```
function countryChange() {
    $("[id^='_Q6_Q'],[id^='_Q'], [id^='_Q0_Q'], [id^='_Q4_Q0_Q0']").val('');
};
```

You can also do wildcards and partial matches if you like.

Here's the selectors reference guide: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/